# Ruby 'First and Rest' Logic

Tags: ruby, performance, refactoring

My app is reaching a point where I must begin optimizing for performance. I've posted some code from my view that I feel can be improved.

In the view, I am treating the first item in the index a certain way and the rest of the items another way. Each time a new item is iterated over, it is being checked (Ruby asks itself.. does this item have an index of 0?)

I feel like performance can be improved if I can stop that behavior by treating the first item special with `index.first?` and treating the other items another way (without even checking whether they have an index of zero) How can this be done?

```
  <% @links.each_with_index do |link, index| %>
    <% if link.points == 0 then @points = "?" else @points = link.points %>
    <% end %>
    <% if index == 0 then %>
      <h1> First Item </h1>
    <% else %>
      <h1> Everything else </h1>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am thinking about strategy of 'popping' the first item off once it has been rendered, then iterating through the rest of the index? Does anyone see a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: That's how I'd do it....but I seriously doubt that's an issue. It may not be pretty code, but there's no way that's making a serious impact on your rendering times.

Comment: Please do not make assumptions about the performance of code without running actual benchmarks showing that it is actually slow.

Comment: Nothing to do about performance but please consider use ternary operator for at least the first condition.

Comment: Kleber means: `@points = links.points==0 ? '?' : link.points`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this non-destructively like so:

```
first, *rest = *my_array
# Do something with 'first'
rest.each{ |item| … }
```

…where `first` will be the first element (or `nil` if my_array was empty) and `rest` will always be an array (possibly empty).

You can get the same results more easily if it's OK to modify your array:

```
# remove the first item from the array and return it
first = my_array.shift
# do something with 'first'
my_array.each{ |item| … }
```

However, this will only clean up your code; it will make no measurable performance difference.